# Loading and Passing JScript Arrays from/to C# (not C) COM Component

Tags: c#, arrays, com, activex

I have looked at tutorials on jscript arrays, but not seeing it yet. I saw something similar asked but involving Win32 code not .NET.

Wondering, how do I pass arrays back and forth between JScript and a C# COM component?

For example, I have two properties defined in my C# COM that returns string and integer arrays as:

```
string[] HeaderLines { get; set; }
int[] ImagePixels { get; set; }
```

In my test.js file:

```
...

var T = new ActiveXObject("Imager.Reader"); 
...    
var headerLines = T.HeaderLines;
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine("First HeaderLine:" + headerLines[0]);
var pixels = T.ImagePixels;
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine("First Pixel: " + pixels[0]);
```

The error is where headerLines[0] is written out: C:\temp\test.js(12, 1) Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'headerLines.0' is null or not an object

If I remove the headerLines in test.js, then I get this error (essentially the same but for the integer array): C:\temp\test.js(12, 1) Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'pixels.0' is null or not an object

I can get results from non-array properties just fine as well as passing values to other methods, but not with arrays. I also need to pass in string and integer arrays into a method defined in my C# COM component as:

```
bool Write(string filename, string[] headerLines, int[] pix, int width, int height);
```

I am using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Desktop for creating the COM piece in C#. If any other information is needed, just let me know.

Comment: have you tried calling `length` to see if it is an array?

Comment: thanks. I get the error: "C:\temp\test.js(12, 1) Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'headerLines.length' is null or not an object". To test.js I added the following to get this error:var headerLines = T.HeaderLines;
var headerLinesLength = headerLines.length;
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine("HeaderLine Length:" + headerLinesLength);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft JScript engine implements JavaScript arrays as `IDispatchEx` objects. From C#, they can be manipulated via reflection or as `dynamic` objects (with `dynamic`, it's only possible to access properties and methods like `length`, `push()` etc., but not reference actual elements by their indices). Example:

**JavaScript:**

```
var T = new ActiveXObject("MySimulator.World"); 

var ar = ["a", "b", "c"];

T.MyFunction(ar);
```

**C#:**

```
public void MyFunction(object array)
{
    dynamic dynArray = array;
    int length = dynArray.length;
    dynArray.push("d");

    SetAt(array, 1, "bb"); 

    Console.WriteLine("MyFunction called, array.length: " + length);
    Console.WriteLine("array[0]: " + GetAt(array, 0));
    Console.WriteLine("array[1]: " + GetAt(array, 1));
    Console.WriteLine("array[3]: " + GetAt(array, 3));
}

static object GetAt(object array, int index)
{
    return array.GetType().InvokeMember(index.ToString(),
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty,
        null, array, new object[] { });
}

static object SetAt(object array, int index, object value)
{
    return array.GetType().InvokeMember(index.ToString(),
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty,
        null, array, new object[] { value });
}
```

**Output:**

```
MyFunction called, array.length: 3
array[0]: a
array[1]: bb
array[3]: d
```

Comment: Noseratio - thanks for all of the very good answers you have been providing! Does this answer mean I cannot use the arrays directly in jscript? I was hoping I could get back the string and integer arrays (i.e. HeaderLines and ImagePixels) mentioned at top and print them out directly (or portions of them). It sounds like I cannot? What is strange though is that when I query the length in jscript of my returned string and integer arrays I get an error (see my previous comment on this original post). Any ideas why this is happening? Thanks again for all of your help.

Comment: @Buck, no you cannot use JavaScript arrays directly or substitute them with C# arrays. They're not actual arrays in common sense, rather, they're objects. Deal with them as with objects, it should not be a big obstacle. If you need to pass a C# array to JavaScript, wrap it as an object (with `Length`, `GetAt`, `SetAt` methods) and pass the object to JavaScript.

Comment: @Buck, on a side note, if you just need a scripting glue for you .NET object, consider using [PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb978526.aspx). It will give you much more than Windows Scripting Host does, and you could leave the COM/interop stuff behind.

Comment: Great to hear about PowerShell - thanks! Also, your other answers were the core of my understanding how jscript worked so I could implement a final solution. Based on that, it is rock solid. Best,