# Convert c# array to javascript array

Tags: c#, javascript, arrays, browser, webbrowser-control

I have a `windows Dotnet` application with a `webbrowser` Control. 
on a button click it calls to a `javascript` function with parameter and javascript try to convert that received parameter to array. Below is my C# and JavaScript Code

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            webBrowser1.DocumentText = @"<html><head>
                <script type='text/javascript'>
                    function doIt(val) 
                    {
                        data = String(val);
                        chartval = new Array(data);
                        //alert('Method Invoked..................' + data);
                        for (var i = 0; i < chartval.length; i++) 
                            {
                               alert('invoked.....'+chartval[i]);
                            }
                        return 'i did it!';
                    }
                </script>
                </head><body>hello!</body></html>";

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string tempstring="[abcd],[efgh],[ijkl]";
            string []objarr=new string[1];
            objarr[0] = tempstring;

            object y = webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("doIt", objarr);
            MessageBox.Show(y.ToString());
        }
```

here `tempstring` has thousand values. I want to convert the `tempstring` value to a javascript array

now I have alert having text

`invoked..... [abcd],[efgh],[ijkl]`

I want 3 alert with text

```
invoked..... abcd
invoked..... efgh
invoked..... ijkl
```

Comment: what are these `[...]` signs for? I don't see any reason here to use them but one, as if you have a 2 dimensional array like `[[...],[...],[...]]`, I think you have just a simple array like `["abcd","efgh","ijkl"]`, please correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: @MehranHatami this is just a model snippet based on my project. I gets this kind of array 'string tempstring="[abcd],[efgh],[ijkl]"' from the system, so I had use it as it is and in actual it contains thousands of values like that.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate: [Loading and Passing JScript Arrays from/to C# (not C) COM Component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20941906/loading-and-passing-jscript-arrays-from-to-c-sharp-not-c-com-component).

Answer (score 0):

in your javascript do this:

```
function doIt(val){
    val = String(val);
    var chartval = val.substring(1, val.length - 1).split("],[");
    for (var i = 0; i < chartval.length; i++){
        alert('invoked.....'+chartval[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is just a model snippet based on my project. I gets this kind of array 'string tempstring="[abcd],[efgh],[ijkl]"' from the system, so I had use it as it is and in actual it contains thousands of values like that.